Combine every unique value from column A with duplicated values into a new sheet
I need to combine each unique value in column A that has duplicate values into a new sheet. This value is duplicated, because every time the record in column A changes status, it creates a new row, with the new status and date of the change in column F.
I need to combine all this data in a single row for each unique value. I have tried it, but I don't know if it is the best way. Also, I have not been able to calculate the days between each status change in column F and neither I got him to order them from the oldest state to the newest.
I leave you an example of my sheet, with a single unique value and the code that I managed to run.
Sub Consolidate()
    ' Iniciamos declarando variables para las hojas de origen y destino
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    ' Variables para iterar y almacenar la última fila de la hoja de origen
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
    ' Diccionario para almacenar valores únicos y una variable para las claves
    Dim uniqueValues As Object, key As Variant
    ' Variables de rango para celdas y búsqueda
    Dim cell As Range, findRange As Range
    ' Variable para rastrear filas en la hoja de destino
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String ' Declaración faltante en el código original, necesaria para el control del bucle

    Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' Usamos un diccionario en lugar de una colección

    ' Estableciendo las hojas de origen y destino
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    wsDest.Name = "Consolidated" ' Nombre para la nueva hoja

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Calcula la última fila con datos en la columna A
    
    ' Recopilando valores únicos de la Columna A y asociando valores de la Columna C
    For Each cell In wsSource.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If Not uniqueValues.Exists(cell.value) Then
            uniqueValues.Add cell.value, wsSource.Cells(cell.Row, "C").value ' Asociamos el valor de la columna C
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Preparando encabezados en la hoja de destino
    With wsDest
        .Cells(1, 1).value = "Work Order" ' Estableciendo el primer encabezado de columna
        .Cells(1, 2).value = "Type" ' Nuevo encabezado para el tipo asociado
        For i = 1 To 12
            .Cells(1, i * 2 + 1).value = "WO Status " & i
            .Cells(1, i * 2 + 2).value = "Status Date " & i
        Next i
    End With

    ' Bucle a través de cada orden de trabajo única
    destRow = 2
    For Each key In uniqueValues
        wsDest.Cells(destRow, 1).value = key ' Escribe el valor único en la primera columna
        wsDest.Cells(destRow, 2).value = uniqueValues(key) ' Escribe el tipo asociado en la segunda columna
        j = 0 ' Inicializar desplazamiento de columna para la hoja de destino
        
        ' Búsqueda de filas con el valor de la clave actual y recopilar datos relacionados
        Set findRange = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(what:=key, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = findRange.Address
            Do
                j = j + 1
                wsDest.Cells(destRow, j * 2 + 1).value = wsSource.Cells(findRange.Row, "E").value ' Copiar fecha
                wsDest.Cells(destRow, j * 2 + 2).value = wsSource.Cells(findRange.Row, "F").value ' Copiar valor asociado
                ' Intentar encontrar la próxima ocurrencia
                Set findRange = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).FindNext(findRange)
                ' Condiciones de salida
                If j >= 12 Or findRange Is Nothing Or findRange.Address = firstAddress Then Exit Do
            Loop
        End If
        
        destRow = destRow + 1 ' Mover a la siguiente fila para el siguiente valor único
    Next key

    ' Definir formato de fecha en columnas con fechas
    Range("D:D,F:F,H:H,J:J,L:L,N:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@"
    
    ' Variables adicionales para el rango de la tabla y la tabla en sí
    Dim tblRange As Range
    Dim ListObj As ListObject
    Dim LastCol As Long

    ' Encontramos la última fila con datos en la hoja "Consolidated"
    lastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Encontramos la última columna con datos en la hoja "Consolidated"
    LastCol = wsDest.Cells(1, wsDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Estableciendo el rango para la nueva tabla basada en los datos
    Set tblRange = wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(1, 1), wsDest.Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

    ' Creando la tabla en el rango especificado
    Set ListObj = wsDest.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tblRange, , xlYes)

    ' Opcionalmente, asignar un nombre a la tabla
    ListObj.Name = "Table_Consolidated"

    ' Estableciendo el estilo de tabla por defecto (cambiar según necesidad)
    ListObj.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

End Sub


"order them from the oldest state to the newest" you can do this by sorting the source data by Work Order and then by Status Date.

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim oDicSta As Object, oDicDate As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, iR As Long, sKey, ColCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), j As Long, aTxt
    Set oDicSta = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicDate = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' sort table
    rngData.Sort key1:=rngData.Columns(1), key2:=rngData.Columns(6), Header:=xlYes
    ' load data into array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' load group data into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 3)
        If Not oDicSta.exists(sKey) Then
            Set oDicSta(sKey) = New Collection
            Set oDicDate(sKey) = New Collection
        End If
        oDicSta(sKey).Add arrData(i, 5)
        oDicDate(sKey).Add arrData(i, 6)
    Next i
    ' get the max count of status
    For Each sKey In oDicSta.Keys
        If oDicSta(sKey).Count > ColCnt Then
            ColCnt = oDicSta(sKey).Count
        End If
    Next
    ReDim arrRes(1 To oDicSta.Count + 1, 1 To ColCnt * 3 + 2)
    ' populate header
    arrRes(1, 1) = "WorkOrder": arrRes(1, 2) = "Type"
    For j = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(1, j * 3) = "WO Status " & j
        arrRes(1, j * 3 + 1) = "Status Date " & j
        If j < ColCnt Then arrRes(1, j * 3 + 2) = "Days bn Status"
    Next
    iR = 1
    ' populate output array
    For Each sKey In oDicSta.Keys
        aTxt = Split(sKey, "|")
        iR = iR + 1
        arrRes(iR, 1) = aTxt(0)
        arrRes(iR, 2) = aTxt(1)
        For j = 1 To oDicSta(sKey).Count
            Debug.Print oDicSta(sKey)(j), oDicDate(sKey)(j)
            arrRes(iR, j * 3) = oDicSta(sKey)(j)
            arrRes(iR, j * 3 + 1) = oDicDate(sKey)(j)
            If j < oDicSta(sKey).Count Then
                arrRes(iR, j * 3 + 2) = oDicDate(sKey)(j + 1) - oDicDate(sKey)(j) + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ' write data to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(oDicSta.Count + 1, ColCnt * 3 + 2) = arrRes
End Sub


